# Override method Header() and its internal methods in http.ResponseWriter in Golang

Tags: go

I am trying to override the methods of ResponseWriter where the Write and WriteHeader functions worked as given below

```
type MyResponseWriter struct {
    http.ResponseWriter
}

func (w *MyResponseWriter) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    //my stuff here
}

func (w *MyResponseWriter) WriteHeader(code int) {
    // my stuff here
}
```

Similarly i want to override the method Header() of http.ResponseWriter,

```
func (r *NewResponseWriter) Header() http.Header {
    return ?
}
```

and also methods of Header like Set(),Get() inside it.
So whenever i call methods like
**MyResponseWriter.Header().Set()**
, **MyResponseWriter.Header().Get()** , **MyResponseWriter.Header()**
my overriden methods should execute how can this happen

Comment: Write your own implementation of `http.ResponseWriter` (which is an interface), and pass your implementation to the handler. Your implementation may do whatever you want to, and likely it will call methods of the "original" response writer too. You may want to inject your implementation in a middleware.

Comment: One thing to note: `http.ResponseWriter` requires to return `http.Header`, so you can't change / add methods to the returned `http.Header` (it's defined in the standard lib), but you can inspect / change the headers in `WriteHeader()` method before they are actually sent.